# Running Selenium python scripts on different server IPs

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a few Selenium scripts written in Python that I need to run on different server IPs i.e. the website is hosted on multiple servers and I need to run each of the scripts on each of the available server IPs. For e.g. the first time, the script should send the request to aa.bb.cc.dd and the next time it should send it to aa.bb.cc.ee. What is the best way to do this that does not involve changing any of the code in the scripts?

Comment: You need to parameterize your tests. The target URL needs to be passed from "outside". You can do it through introducing custom config files, or via command line or..there are many ways to do that.

Comment: Say I parameterize the first URL. How about the subsequent ones that the script access either through clicks or wd.get?